# Error JUnit and Eclipse Indigo

Tags: unit-testing, junit, eclipse-indigo

I have many projects in my eclipse (Indigo, I can't migrate to Juno) setup by maven. All projects run unit test fine except one.
When I run it, I get this message as if eclipse doesn't find the jvm:

```
Usage: javaw [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  javaw [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
```

This project has the same configuration as others so I don't understand why these unit tests don't run.

To run it, I do "right click" on the project and "Run as" -> "Junit test"

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is there anything in the error log of eclipse? Window->Show View->General->Error Log.

Comment: Nothing happend in the Error Log